# jQuery Datatables won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

So I followed everything on the basic example at : http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Unfortunately, My current table stays in the bootstrap style and nothing of the DataTable is shown, No errors occurred. If you see anything wrong please let me know.

Table design :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="mw_table">
           <thead>
           <th>Volledige naam</th>
           <th>E-mail</th>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           @foreach($medewerkers as $medewerker)
           <tr>
           <td>{{$medewerker->voornaam . ' ' . substr($medewerker->tussenvoegsel,0,5) . ' ' . $medewerker->achternaam}}</td>
           <td>{{$medewerker->email}}</td>
           <td>
           {{--<input type="hidden" class="zoeknaam2" value="{{$project->projectnaam}}"  name="zoeknaam2" class="form-control" placeholder="Projectnaam">--}}
           <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs wijzigKnop2" name="zoekProject" type="button" data-project="{{$medewerker->email}}">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
           </button>
           </td>
           <td>
           <a href="/verwijderGebruiker/{{$medewerker->id}}" class="">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
           </button>
           </a>
           </td>
           </tr>
           @endforeach
           </tbody>
           </table>
           </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#mw_table').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

Includes:

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('../assets/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why datatable is called twice and where is your bootstrap js?

Comment: whoops mybad copied it double. bootsatrap.js is present i have this : <script src="{{URL::asset('../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>

Comment: it would be good if you could create a demo and share.

Comment: okay one question does it matter i use http:// links when im on localhost?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/49eqzd8r/

Comment: It works if you learn to load scripts _before_ you actually try to use them, and if you are loading scripts in jsfiddle via "external resources" using `https://` -> https://jsfiddle.net/49eqzd8r/2/

Answer (score 0):

got it working. builded an new datatables library in the Downloader of their website and voila!